# Xcode bot error: Unable to find a destination

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server

Recently updated to **Xcode 9.3** and created a new Xcode Server bot. When trying to run the bot I'm getting an error:

> xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided
>   destination specifier:        { id:05FEBEC4-44CC-416E-A59D-7B0F9D508E25 }

My deployment targets match both in the build settings and the podfiles. I've also checked the Xcode server account that it has the available simulator to test with. With Xcode it could be something else though.

Thanks

Comment: I've checked the id in the simulator list and it references a sim for iOS 10.0 - which I'm not testing for under this proj

Comment: Do you specify certain devices and simulators to test on in your bot configuration? This affected me during the last update to 9.3 where the previously selected devices & simulators where no longer available to test with. I had update the bot configuration to select the new simulators I desired to test with.